# How to set tomcat's context attribute via Apache Ant-style variable substitution in command line?

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm

I'd like to make `unloadDelay` attribute of context configurable before starting tomcat. Currently, I use `sed` to replace the value. However, I found that it can be configured by `Apache Ant-style variable substitution`. I tried to find out the `-D` syntax parameter name, I didn't though.
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/index.html

So, Could someone tell me the exact parameter name for configuring `unloadDelay` or the patter to build any parameter related to tomcat configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:
Start your tomcat from command line:

```
bin/startup -app.unloadingDelay 60000
```

modify your conf/context.xml and use above property:

```
<Context unloadDelay="${app.unloadingDelay}"> 

<!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

<!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
<!--
<Manager pathname="" />
-->

<!-- Uncomment this to enable Comet connection tacking (provides events
     on session expiration as well as webapp lifecycle) -->
<!--
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.CometConnectionManagerValve" />
-->
```

Don't use any keyword or attributes as the property names.
reference: 
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/index.html

> Tomcat configuration files are formatted as schemaless XML; elements and attributes are case-sensitive. Apache Ant-style variable substitution is supported; a system property with the name propname may be used in a configuration file using the syntax ${propname}. All system properties are available including those set using the -D syntax, those automatically made available by the JVM and those configured in the $CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties file.

Detailed:

> https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-3.3-doc/serverxml.html#substitution

Comment: Thank you very much. Finally, I used this `-Dapp.unloadDelay=60000` format.